TCP Listener in .NET 8 deployed on Ubuntu Server environment Responds Slowly Compared to Local Execution
I have a TCP listener application written in .NET 8 which is supposed to listen for incoming client connection, accept connection and process the the massage that comes in and responds to the client.
Locally when I run the TCP listener and client, I am able to send message from the client to the listener and the listener responds fast as it should.
Below is the code for the listener, Please note the listener processes an ISO8583 message
public class TcpServerHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    IPAddress _ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    int _port = 2000;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<TcpServerHostedService> _logger;

    public TcpServerHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        ILogger<TcpServerHostedService> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }



    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(_ipAddress, _port);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("EchoServer started...");
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for incoming client connections...");
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Accepted new client connection...");
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            try
            {
                using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var _transactionService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAfslTransactionService>();
                    var _mailService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMailService>();


                    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        // Read the header bytes
                        byte[] headerBytes = new byte[2];
                        stream.Read(headerBytes, 0, 2);

                        // Calculate the message length based on the header bytes
                        int messageLength = headerBytes[0] * 256 + headerBytes[1];

                        // Receive data from the client
                        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[messageLength];
                        int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length);

                        // Convert received bytes to string
                        string receivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead);


                        // Process the ISO 8583 message
                        string response = await ProcessIsoMessage(receivedData, _transactionService, _mailService);



                        // Convert string message to bytes using UTF-8 encoding
                        string message = response;
                        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                        // Get the length of the message and convert it to bytes (using 2 bytes for simplicity)
                        byte[] resheaderBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)messageBytes.Length);

                        // Ensure the bytes are in network byte order (big endian)
                        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                        {
                            Array.Reverse(resheaderBytes);
                        }

                        // Send the length header bytes to the stream
                        await stream.WriteAsync(resheaderBytes, 0, resheaderBytes.Length);

                        // Send the actual message bytes to the stream
                        await stream.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);

                        await stream.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred on TCP");
            }
        }
    }


    private async Task<string> ProcessIsoMessage(string isoMessage, IAfslTransactionService _transactionService, IMailService _mailService)
    {
        MessageParser.NET.Tools.ISO8583 iso = new MessageParser.NET.Tools.ISO8583();
        string[] data = iso.Parse(isoMessage);


        Dictionary<int, string> isoFields = ParseStringArrayToDictionary(data);

        string messageTypeCode = isoFields.ContainsKey(0) ? isoFields[0] : "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageTypeCode))
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> result = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            switch (messageTypeCode)
            {
                case "0100":
                    result = await _transactionService.ProcessHoldReleaseFunds(isoFields);
                    break;
                case "0200":
                    result = await _transactionService.ProcessFinancialTransaction(isoFields);
                    break;
                case "0420":
                    result = await _transactionService.ProcessReversal(isoFields);
                    break;
                case "0800":
                    result = await _transactionService.ProcessNetworkManagement(isoFields);
                    break;
            }

            //Message Type Identifier (Financial Message Response)
            string MTI = result[0];

            //1. Create Arrays AND Assign corresponding data to each array
            string[] DE = ParseDictionaryToStringArray(result);

            //3.Use "Build" method of object iso8583 to create a new  message.
            string NewISOmsg = iso.Build(DE, MTI);

            // Send ISO MESSAGE
            return NewISOmsg;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }


    static Dictionary<int, string> ParseStringArrayToDictionary(string[] array)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // Extract key and value from the item
            int key = i; // Assuming keys are single digits
            string value = array[i];

            // Check if key is "129", assign it to key "0" in dictionary
            if (key == 129)
            {
                dictionary[0] = value;
            }
            // Check if key is "0" or "1", merge them and assign to key "1" in dictionary
            else if (key == 0 || key == 1)
            {
                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(1))
                {
                    dictionary[1] += value;
                }
                else
                {
                    dictionary[1] = value;
                }
            }
            // Check if the value is not "null"
            else if (value != null)
            {
                dictionary[key] = value;
            }
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    static string[] ParseDictionaryToStringArray(Dictionary<int, string> dictionary)
    {
        dictionary.Remove(0);
        dictionary.Remove(1);
        string[] DE = new string[130];

        for (int i = 0; i < DE.Length; i++)
        {
            string value;

            dictionary.TryGetValue(i, out value);

            DE[i] = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : null;
        }

        return DE;
    }

}

The problem I am facing here is that when I deploy the listener on an ubuntu server I send a message from the TCP Client to the listener and it takes time to respond sometimes even up to 3-5 minutes and this is not good.
Just to mention, I have an Nginx server that handles incoming request for Stream and sends it to my application on the ubuntu server but I don't think the nginx is the problem because I tried binding the application port to the server port direction and I still got same issue of delayed response.
Please has anyone faced this type of challenge and what can I do to resolve this issue, because this doesn't look like a code issue

If you can reproduce this with .NET 8, you might open an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues. .NET 7 reached end of life so no one should use it any more.

I have upgraded the project to .NET 8, whether .NET 7 or 8 the problem still remains  the same.

Are you sure that the problem is in TCP client and not _transactionService for example? Have you tried logging execution times of different parts of the process or better - tracing/profiling?

No it's not, I mention the application work well on my local environment but when deployed on the server it sometime takes time to get to my application and when the response has left my application it also delays before reaching the client
so the request and response is delay on the server and I have tried everything I can but it still persist

@Kefas "I mention the application work well on my local environment but when deployed on the server" - that doesn't prove that the problem is with TCP client. "it also delays before reaching the client so the request and response is delay on the server" - how have you measured that?

There is nothing evident in the code you've shared that looks like it would cause such slowdowns. Like Guru Stron suggested, you should log execution times of different parts of your code to see if there is a bottleneck somewhere. As the methods of _transactionService are called Process"Something", they look like they do some potential heavy lifting, maybe even other network requests. I would definitely start by profiling those.

After that, I would move on to the NGINX server and look at whether that causes any bottlenecks. If possible, open up the ports and try connecting to the application directly instead of using NGINX as a proxy, and see if it makes a difference. Also, while I am not familiar with how hosted services in ASP.NET Core work, I would also look into if that could cause any issues, maybe recreating the TCP server in a standalone console application instead.

Well, for one thing, your message framing code is incorrect. I explain what message framing is on my blog. A red flag for this is stream.Read with a discarded return code - such code must be wrong; there is no way for it to be correct.
Since you're on .NET 8, there's some nifty ReadExactly methods available:
// Read the header bytes
byte[] headerBytes = new byte[2];
stream.ReadExactly(headerBytes);

// Calculate the message length based on the header bytes
int messageLength = headerBytes[0] * 256 + headerBytes[1];

// Receive data from the client
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[messageLength];
await stream.ReadExactlyAsync(receiveBuffer);

Is this the cause of the slowdown? Maybe. If your client automatically retries its requests (with a delay) and if the first (few?) try failed, then it could cause what would appear to be a slowdown.

You are correct the delay is caused on stream.Read. And again I was running the TCP server in a Web API instead of a separate worker service project.

Nice catch on the first Stream.Read call. ReadExactly is a very interesting new method. I haven't dug too deep in all new .NET features for a while, thus I didn't learn about it until now. This is very useful as I do a lot of networking which requires precise reads. Funnily enough I implemented my own version of this very recently for a personal project of mine in .NET 6, not long before .NET 8 was released.
